# Strange behaviour with Add-Member. Get-Member doesn't return any value

Tags: powershell

If i write the following code and, as u can see, I use Get-Member I get a null:

```
$UserToAdd = New-Object psobject
$UserToAdd | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value ([adsi]$_.path).name[0]
$UserToAdd | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -Name "Email" -Value ([adsi]$_.path).mail[0]
$UserToAdd | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -Name "DaysLeft" -Value $DaysTillExpiring
$UserToAdd | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -Name "ExpirationTimestamp" -Value $ExpirationTimestamp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy alle ore HH:mm:ss ")
$UserToAdd | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -Name "SamAccountName" -Value ([adsi]$_.path).SamAccountName[0]
$UserToAdd | get-member -Verbose
get-content $UserToAdd
```

But the variable does have a value, because when I use something like `get-content` I get the following error, containing the correct value:

> get-content : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '@{Name=XXXXXXXXX; Email=XXXXXXXXXX; DaysLeft=13; ExpirationTimestamp=27/04/2014 alle ore 10' does not exist.

Comment: what's your PS version?

Comment: PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Host | Select-Object version

Version                                                                                                                                                                                     
-------                                                                                                                                                                                     
4.0

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem on PS 4.0. Everything works fine after you remove the `Get-Content` part that should never be there in the first place.

```
$UserToAdd = New-Object psobject
$UserToAdd | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value "hei"
$UserToAdd | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -Name "Email" -Value "epost"
$UserToAdd | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -Name "DaysLeft" -Value 3
$UserToAdd | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -Name "ExpirationTimestamp" -Value ((date).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy alle ore HH:mm:ss "))
$UserToAdd | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -Name "SamAccountName" -Value "ops"
$UserToAdd | get-member -Verbose


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name                MemberType   Definition                                                     
----                ----------   ----------                                                     
Equals              Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                 
GetHashCode         Method       int GetHashCode()                                              
GetType             Method       type GetType()                                                 
ToString            Method       string ToString()                                              
DaysLeft            NoteProperty System.Int32 DaysLeft=3                                        
Email               NoteProperty System.String Email=epost                                      
ExpirationTimestamp NoteProperty System.String ExpirationTimestamp=14.04.2014 alle ore 16:40:48 
Name                NoteProperty System.String Name=hei                                         
SamAccountName      NoteProperty System.String SamAccountName=ops
```

If `Get-Member` returns null, then you never created the object in the first place, because even without the `Add-Member` lines, `Get-Member` would still display this:

```
$UserToAdd = New-Object psobject
$UserToAdd | get-member -Verbose


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType Definition                    
----        ---------- ----------                    
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method     type GetType()                
ToString    Method     string ToString()
```

Comment: Thank you but, as u can see, on line 7 i wrote a Get-Member to debug the problem but it returns null.

Comment: Ahh, my bad. Still, the `Get-Content` command will always fail, so remove that and the error. It's just confusing. As for the script before `Get-Content`: everything works on PS 4.0 when I run it here(with dummy values). See updated answer.

Comment: Actually everything works, cause this is part of a bigger script. I'm modifying it cause i want to add a functionality but i cant add something like $UserToAdd.name cause it is null. This appears nonsensical because, in the end, the whole script works and this part is fundamental for it. In this sense it is also very strange that get-member returns null.

Comment: Also check the second piece of code i posted... Here Get-content returns an error, obviously cause i used it only for a test on the content, but what it returns in the error (i edited where you find XXXXXX) is right. When i use the value it is null, even if i just recall it without any cmdlet. By the way i tried to put in a variable the first NoteProperty (which is ([adsi]$_.path).name[0] ) and, when i recall the variable, it returns null... Seems something related to powershell itself. It's very strange...

Comment: The only logical reason I can come up with at this point is that your object is in a different scope, but as long as you run all the commands as a script or by pressing the green play-button in PS ISE, then it shouldn't be a problem. I'm sorry, but I can't reproduce the error.